# Does $\frac{1}{x}=0$ have a solution?

Tags: calculus, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, infinity

> Does $\frac{1}{x}=0$ have a solution ?

since any number multiplied by 0 equals 0，this equation has no solution in elementary math. I wonder is there a solution in higher mathematics.

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "has a solution." In any field, there is an extended space called the projective line, which is the field plus a symbol $\infty$, where the function $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ extends naturally to $f(\infty)=0$. There is a sense to this, but you have to be *really* careful when talking about that symbol, $\infty$.

Comment: Look up "finite field". In a finite field of order $q$ one can write $\frac{1}{0} = 0^{q-1} = 0$.

Comment: No, that is not true. @LJL Have no idea where you got that. $0^q=0$, not $0^q=1$, in $\mathbb F_q$. There is no sense that $\frac{1}{0}=0$ in finite fields.

Comment: The "projective line," interestingly, comes up most in beginning math as the "Riemannian Sphere," starting from the field of complex numbers and adding the symbol $\infty$. It literally is a sphere, in some sense, and certain parts of it make a *lot* more sense with $\infty$ rather than without - for example, Möbius transformations. But you have to be very careful about it. I keep calling it a symbol because it is dangerous in general to treat it as a number.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I made a mistake; that should have been "$0^{q-2}$". I imagine you still don't like that, but I've seen $x \mapsto \frac{1}{x}$ defined as $x^{q-2}$ in some places in order to include $0$ in the domain without having to write any extra text. I should have specified that it is an infrequently-used and nonstandard definition in my original comment, but it is too late to edit.

Comment: you may write as this $\frac{1}{x}=e^i(theta)+1=0$, then $x= 1\(cos(theta)+i*sin(theta)+1)$, where $i=sqrt(-1)$ and $e$ is the base of the natural logarithm

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the number system you are working in. This equation has solutions in the [extended real number line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_real_number_line) for example.

However, the extended real number line doesn't have very many nice properties. It's not a not a field or ring for example. This means that you lose the ability to do even simple things like cancelling. For this reason it's often avoided.

Answer (score 3):

No, it does not. This is because $x\frac{1}{x}=1$. This would not be possible if $\frac{1}{x}$ was zero, as $x\frac{1}{x}$ would be $x\cdot0=0$

---

You may also want to read on [wheels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheel_theory), they are structures in which division is always defined, although I don't recommend you go in very deep just yet.